# How can I monitor memory used by specific process in AWS cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scripting, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to monitor memory used by particular process under `cloudwatch` in `AWS`. Do I have to use script to do so? If yes, let me know the steps or some guideline or Can I use `cloudwatch logs` to report memory utilized by particular process in real time? Tell me the other alternatives as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you will need a script that runs on the instance you want to monitor. Cloudwatch by default can only report on things it can 'see' at the hypervisor level, not things that re going on 'inside', so you'll need to create and report 'custom metrics'.

Here are some Linux script pointers:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html

and some for windows:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts-powershell.html

Comment: The first link you've provided appears broken.  It now redirects to [What Is Amazon CloudWatch?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsCloudWatch.html)

Comment: I fixed the link for you.

Comment: I don't think it can report memory utilized by particular process in real time. first the mininal interval of cloudwatch is 60s and second the Linux script pasted above is for Linux/System as whole, not particular process

Comment: @Jrgns - the second link goes to "Monitor memory and disk metrics for Amazon EC2 Linux instances" . Maybe they took the PowerShell page down for some reason?

Comment: Poked around a bit  more- one useful related link might be https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-cw.html which is about how to use PowerShell to submit custom metrics.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a file called 001initial.config in your .ebextensions folder of your s3 bucket you're using for your app ver. This will install the monitoring and set it up as a cron job.
Note the perl modules that get installed. 
You'll want to ssh into your box and test the script is running.

Go into security and update your iam role for you ec2 instance with CloudWatch rights. Make sure to select the checkbox for the role and then click it to get to the rights page.

Once you know monitoring is running, go to the cloud watch page, and from the very first page type in System/Linux and search for that and it will show you disk and memory stats.

```
--- 
files:
  "/etc/cron.d/my_cron":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # run a cloudwatch command every five minutes (as ec2-user)
      */5 * * * * ec2-user ~/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail --disk-space-util --disk-path=/ --from-cron
encoding: plain
commands:
  # delete backup file created by Elastic Beanstalk
  clear_cron_backup:
    command: rm -f /etc/cron.d/watson.bak
container_commands:
    02download:
        command: "curl http://aws-cloudwatch.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.1.zip -O"
        ignoreErrors: true
    03extract:
        command: "unzip CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.1.zip"
        ignoreErrors: true
    04rmzip:
        command: "rm rm CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.1.zip"
        ignoreErrors: true
    05cdinto:
        command: "mv aws-scripts-mon/ /home/ec2-user"
        ignoreErrors: true
packages: 
    yum: 
        perl-Switch : []
        perl-URI: [] 
        perl-Bundle-LWP: []
        perl-DateTime: [] 
        perl-Sys-Syslog: []
        perl-LWP-Protocol-https: []
```

Comment: Cool, but note it's Linux-only.

Answer (score 0):

While the reason provided by @EJBrennan in his answer is correct, **a more recent update to this question** is to simply install the scripts as provided in this excellent documentation from AWS

[AWS Documentation for Memory & Disk Metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html)

So you need to

1. Install the scripts in your EC2 server
2. PUT the logs to Cloudwatch using   `./mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used-incl-cache-buff --mem-used --mem-avail`
3. Setup a dashboard in your cloudwatch to see the metrics.

Alternatively, you can also setup a cron job to get the metrics on a periodic basis.

Hope that helps

Comment: Well, that's a Linux-only solution. OP doesn't indicate Linux as his EC2 OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try AWS CloudWatch procstat plugin. Apart from memory using `memory_data` param of procstat, you can monitor many other data of process. I have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70643572/5832570).

A sample JSON configuration file using procstat -

```
    {
   "agent":{
      "metrics_collection_interval":60,
      "region":"us-south-1",
      "logfile":"/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/process-monitoring.log"
   },
   "metrics":{
      "namespace":"CWAgent",
      "append_dimensions":{
         "AutoScalingGroupName":"${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}"
      },
      "aggregation_dimensions":[
         [
            "AutoScalingGroupName"
         ]
      ],
      "force_flush_interval":60,
      "metrics_collected":{
         "procstat":[
            {
               "pid_file":"/var/opt/data/myapp/tmp/sampleApp.pid",
               "measurement":[
                  "memory_data",
                  "memory_locked",
                  "memory_rss"
               ],
               "metrics_collection_interval":30
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```